# Upload data to a collection (pojo list) of App engine data store

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have a GAE entity (via JPA) of the following form:

```
@Entity
public class QuestionDB {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  private String question;

  private ArrayList<String> options;

  private int answer;
}
```

How can I bulk upload data to this DB? I am trying to use the data upload mechanism using csv files as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial#cus)
. Also what structure of csv should be to incorporate the list of string?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

1. Deploy your CSV file with your project, or upload it through the UI.
2. Process it.

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), for example, to process the file.

UPDATE;

You can use OpenCSV both to create a CSV file and to process it.

Comment: Im actually more confused about the structure of the csv file to incorporate the string list

Comment: Then you have to explain your problem in more detail. What stops you from adding multiple values into a single "cell", and then splitting them into an array when you process it?

Comment: Yeah andrei, i updated my question for that. If i understand correctly you are asking me to add the strings with a new delimitor and process for that while processing, for e.g. Use semicolon to create a single delimited string and add it to that cell?

Comment: If you create your CSV file using Excel, you can add values separated by commas or a special symbol like ### (to make sure that none of the values contain it). Even if you use commas, Excel knows how to save it correctly. Then use OpenCSV or similar library to parse your CSV file. Also, see an update to my answer.